# how can display all of images in imageview

Tags: android

**I am new in android and try to do coding to display posters which fetch from API, issue is after run it and then it only displays one poster. Please give me some advise**

1.poster_image.xml

```
<ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/poster"
android:layout_width="500dp"
android:layout_height="60dp" />
```

2.MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ArrayList<String> moviesList = new ArrayList<>();
ImageView mImageView;
String url = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/popular?api_key=(MY API KEY)";
String image_url = "http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.poster_image);


   mImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.poster);

    // Fetch Data from API
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    try {
                        JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("results");

                        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject movies = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                            String poster = movies.getString("poster_path");


                            moviesList.add(poster);
                            Log.i("IS", String.valueOf(moviesList));
                        }


                        for (int j = 0; j < moviesList.size(); j++) {
                            Picasso.with(getApplicationContext())
                                    .load(image_url + moviesList.get(j))
                                    .into(mImageView);

                            Log.i("I", image_url + moviesList.get(j));
                        }

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.e("Error", "Wrong");
                }
            });

    requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
}
}
```

Comment: what should i do if Use ListView? do i need a Adapter ? thanks

Comment: Dont use listView use RecyclerView Create Custom Recycler Adapter

Comment: use listview or  recyclerview(prefered) with an adapter to show a list of imageviews , almost every example of them is shown with a list of images so it will be easy to find

Comment: is there any example please?

Answer (score 0):

You have to make a recylerview to show list of images from server. 
Use Glide ,Picasso and Fresco to load the images from server.
Go through this link. [Show images in recylerview from server](https://www.learn2crack.com/2016/02/image-loading-recyclerview-picasso.html)